# AWS S3 cli throwing error "unknown options: --sse Kms-key-id <key id> , --see aws:kms" when attempting to access S3 bucket via CLI

Tags: amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I'm trying to access a bucket thats been shared to us from another company via the CLI after assuming the role we shared with them and its throwing an error on the KMS key options.  Syntax Im using is "aws s3 ls s3://bucketName --recursive --sse-kms-key-id "keyID" --sse aws:kms"

Anyone run into this before or is there an issue with accessing s3 buckets outside our tenant via cli?

Comment: The options are `--server-side-encryption aws:kms -–ssekms-key-id keyID`, not `--sse-kms-key-id` and `--sse`